# How to check if std::thread is valid

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I got a class object, which only needs in some cases to start a thread. In the destructor it would be convenient for me to know whenever or not there is/was a thread. The question is, how do I detected if a std::thread object is or was a valid thread.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   ~MyClass()
    {
       // Attention pseudocode!!!!!
       if(mythread is a valid object)
           mythread.join();

       if(mythread was a valid object in its lifetime)
           Do some stuff
    }

    void DoSomeStuff()
    {
      // May or may not create a thread
    }
private:
   std::thread mythread;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) function:

```
~MyClass()
{
    if (t.joinable()) { t.join(); }
}
```

Comment: Is it save to use t.joinable() on a threadobject which was never used? The documentation I found was a little bit unclear about that.